# Getting SQL Syntax errors on every attempt to UPDATE myData from a temp table

Tags: mysql

I have a simple table called myData that looks like this:

```
ID     NAME
1      Bob
2      Sue
3      Doug
```

Then I have a temporary table that contains changes a user has made.
TEMP table looks like this:

```
ID     NAME
1      Bobby
2      Sue
3      Douglas
```

All I want to do is update myData with the changes to TEMP.   I have tried this code:

```
UPDATE myData
SET myData.name = temp.name
FROM temp
WHERE myData.id = temp.id;
```

This code:

```
UPDATE myData
SET myData.name = temp.name
FROM myData 
INNER JOIN temp
ON myData.id = temp.id;
```

AND this code:

```
MERGE INTO myData
USING temp
ON myData.id = temp.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET myData.name = temp.name;
```

All of these examples give me a SQL syntax error.   On the first two the FROM seems to be the problem.  On the last example the MERGE seems to be the problem.

I must be missing something obvious.  Any ideas?
I'm using mySQL on mySQLWorkbench if that matters.

UPDATE**********************************

I've gotten rid of the syntax errors by doing this:

```
UPDATE myData, temp
SET myData.name = temp.name
WHERE myData.id = temp.id;
```

But NOW I'm being told that "you are trying to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column".   ID is set up as the Primary Key in both tables, so where is that coming from?

Comment: OK, I see that FROM isn't required for mySQL syntax.  But now I have a new problem.  If I take it out, the error tells me that "temp.id" is an unknown column in the WHERE clause.  (Using first example of code.)

Comment: Play around with second example of code some more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE myData
INNER JOIN temp on myData.id = temp.id
SET myData.name = temp.name;
```

Comment: I'm still getting the error about not having a WHERE that uses a KEY column.   Going to try to turn off safe mode and see what happens.

Comment: OK, when I disable safe mode it works just fine.  But is that wise?

Comment: What if you will add something like: 'where myData.id > 0' ?

Comment: Nope... If I go back to safe mode, I get the same WHERE/KEY column error.   Tried doing a redundant "WHERE myData.id = temp.id".    I think I need to read up on safe mode for mySQL and possibly post another question that just addresses this issue.